# Sum the column in different sheets

Tags: excel, vba, sum

I'm trying to sum a specific column in that repeats in some sheets with Macro Excel and I'm quite lost...

I have 10 different sheets and in each one the column that I'm trying to sum is in a different letter. Also, each sheet has a dynamic count of rows.

Could you show me what code I need to write to sum the column in all the sheets at once?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula to sum or do anything in other sheet:
Example you want to sum the value from A1:A5 in Sheet1 and store it in the B3 in Sheet2, you can use this formula in cell B3 in Sheet2 like this:
=SUM(Sheet1!A1:A3)

Best,
Tung Duong (Thomas)